# Neo4j Cypher query performnce optimization with WHERE condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have the following Cypher query:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (childDStat:JobableStatistic {jobableId: childD.id}) 
WITH collect({`childDStat`:childDStat, `childD`:childD}) as childDStats 
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2(
  " WITH _.childD as childD, _.childDStat as childDStat 
    WITH childD, childDStat 
    UNWIND childD.detailedCriterionIds as dCId 
    WITH childD, childDStat, dCId + coalesce(childDStat['replaceableCriterionIds.' + dCId],[]) as cGroup 
    WITH childD, childDStat, cGroup 
    WHERE NOT AlL(x IN cGroup WHERE x IN $zeroCriterionIds ) 
    WITH childD, childDStat, collect(cGroup) as cGroups 
    WHERE size(cGroups) >= size(childD.detailedCriterionIds) 
    UNWIND cGroups as cGroup 
    WITH childD, childDStat, cGroup 
    WHERE ANY(x IN cGroup WHERE x IN $detailedCriterionIds) 
    WITH childD, childDStat, collect(cGroup) as cGroups 
    WHERE size(cGroups) > 1 
    RETURN childD, childDStat, cGroups ",
  {`detailedCriterionIds`: [3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 23, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 36, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 51, 54],
   `zeroCriterionIds`: []},
  childDStats, 6, 10) 
YIELD value
WITH value.childD as childD, value.childDStat as childDStat, value.cGroups as cGroups WITH collect({`childDStat`:childDStat, `childD`:childD, `cGroups`:cGroups}) as childDStats 

CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2(
  " WITH _.childD as childD, _.childDStat as childDStat, _.cGroups as cGroups WITH childD, childDStat, size(cGroups) as cGroupsSize, cGroups 
    UNWIND cGroups as cGroup 
    WITH childD, childDStat, cGroupsSize, cGroup 
    UNWIND cGroup as cId WITH childD, childDStat, cGroupsSize, cGroup, cId, cGroup[0] as cG0

    WITH childD, childDStat, cGroupsSize, cGroup, cId, cG0, childDStat['criterionAvgVoteWeights.' + cG0] as childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight,
      childDStat['criterionExperienceMonths.' + cG0] as childDStatCriterionExperienceMonth, 
      $criterionAvgVoteWeights[toString(cId)] as criterionAvgVoteWeight, $criterionExperienceMonths[toString(cId)] as criterionExperienceMonth 
    WHERE 
      (childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight = 0 OR childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight <= criterionAvgVoteWeight OR criterionAvgVoteWeight IS NULL) AND
      (childDStatCriterionExperienceMonth = 0 OR childDStatCriterionExperienceMonth <= criterionExperienceMonth OR criterionExperienceMonth IS NULL)

    WITH childD, childDStat, cGroupsSize, cG0, collect(cId) as cIds WITH childD, childDStat, cGroupsSize, collect(DISTINCT cG0 + cIds) as cGroups
    WHERE size(cGroups) >= cGroupsSize
    RETURN childD, childDStat, cGroups ",
  {`detailedCriterionIds`: [3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 23, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 36, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 51, 54],
   `zeroCriterionIds`: [],
   `criterionAvgVoteWeights`: {`51`:5.0, `8`:0.0, `33`:5.0, `21`:0.0, `31`:0.0, `26`:4.0, `14`:5.0, `36`:3.0, `46`:3.0, `12`:3.0, `18`:5.0, `28`:5.0, `16`:2.0, `7`:5.0, `40`:1.0, `5`:5.0, `44`:4.0, `3`:1.0, `54`:4.0, `20`:4.0, `42`:4.0, `30`:3.0, `15`:4.0, `47`:1.0, `35`:1.0, `13`:3.0, `45`:3.0, `23`:4.0, `29`:1.0},
   `criterionExperienceMonths`: {`8`:109, `33`:8, `21`:184, `31`:14, `26`:100, `14`:157, `36`:140, `46`:123, `12`:85, `18`:96, `28`:116, `16`:15, `7`:63, `40`:56, `5`:166, `44`:101, `3`:129, `42`:84, `20`:102, `30`:173, `15`:97, `47`:54, `13`:91, `35`:137, `45`:119, `23`:162, `29`:97}
  },
  childDStats, 6, 10) 
YIELD value
RETURN value.childD.id
```

The following condition takes most of the query execution time:

```
WHERE 
  (childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight = 0 OR childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight <= criterionAvgVoteWeight OR criterionAvgVoteWeight IS NULL) AND
  (childDStatCriterionExperienceMonth = 0 OR childDStatCriterionExperienceMonth <= criterionExperienceMonth OR criterionExperienceMonth IS NULL)
```

With this condition in place the query works `~1000ms`, without it `5ms`.

Is there something I may do with this condition in order to improve the query performance?

P.S

This is just a test query. The real query uses parameters for each single value.

Comment: Please edit your code to avoid the enormous horizontal scrolling needed to read it.

Comment: Sure, edited the query

Comment: I edited further for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `(childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight = 0 OR childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight <= criterionAvgVoteWeight OR criterionAvgVoteWeight IS NULL)`:

- You should test `criterionAvgVoteWeight IS NULL` first. That way, if it is `NULL`, then you would not waste time testing with a `NULL` value in the `childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight <= criterionAvgVoteWeight` expression (which would be considered `false`), and you would also not need to test `childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight = 0`. This could be a big win if the value is frequently `NULL`.
- If `criterionAvgVoteWeight` is always >= 0 (when it is not `NULL`), then the `childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight = 0` test can be eliminated completely.

In short, you could consider using this expression instead: `(criterionAvgVoteWeight IS NULL OR childDStatCriterionAvgVoteWeight <= criterionAvgVoteWeight)`.

Similar considerations apply to `(childDStatCriterionExperienceMonth = 0 OR childDStatCriterionExperienceMonth <= criterionExperienceMonth OR criterionExperienceMonth IS NULL)`.

These changes may save some time, depending on your actual data characteristics, but filtering is not free.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need indexes on the following fields (which are part of the condition in the filtering logic) - `childDStat['criterionAvgVoteWeights.' + cG0]`? I hope not, because I may have up to 100k of such different fields

Comment: At that point in the logic, it is too late to for indexing to be of any help. You'd have to use the index at the top (`MATCH ... WHERE ...`). Besides, as you said, you'd need a ridiculously large number of indexes, which would not be supportable.